# Getting cgo runtime error "cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer"

Tags: go, cgo

I'm using cgo to write a service using a C library that we're using.  I'm new to Go.

I'm having a runtime error on the following line:

```
status  = int(C.VeProtect(C.VeObj(fpeProtect), &argsProtect))
```

The trace I get is:

```
panic serving [::1]:55146: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer
goroutine 20 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x13a
panic({0xc21cc0, 0xc000093700})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x262
voltagems/voltagefuncs.protectAndAccess.func1(0x0, 0xc0000b2960)
    /media/sf_winhome/git/voltagego/voltagefuncs/voltagefuncs.go:71 +0x90
```

First, I can't even tell from this which argument it's talking about, although I would guess it's the first one.

The type of "`fpeProtect` is "`C.VeFPE`", and the type of that is "`*_Ctype_struct_VeFPE_st`".  That struct type has a handful of "`_Ctype_int`" properties, and several "`*_Ctype_char`" properties.  I didn't directly set any properties of that object, it was passed to a couple of C methods that would have populated some of the fields.

If I understand it correctly, the implication of that error message is that one or more properties of that struct is a pointer to a Go object, not a C object.  I don't see how that could be possible, but I also can't tell exactly what property it's complaining about.

**Update**:

@JimB made me realize that the issue is likely with the second parameter, not the first.  I think that's correct, but the assignments associated with that were already complex.

These are the assignments in question:

```
argsProtect.plaintext       = (*C.uchar)(&([]byte)(data)[0])
argsProtect.plaintextSize   = C.uint(len(data))

const BufSize int   = 256

var textBuffer  []byte = make([]byte, BufSize)

argsProtect.ciphertext      = (*C.uchar)(&textBuffer[0])
```

The "data" variable is type "string". The type of both "plaintext" and "ciphertext" is "*_Ctype_uchar".

How can I convert those "plaintext" and "ciphertext" assignments to fulfill the requirement of producing a "*C.uchar", but converting the GoPointer to a CPointer?

**Update**:

I think I may have fixed the ciphertext assignment, but I think the plaintext assignment needs to be fixed also.  Here is the changed block:

```
argsProtect.plaintext       = (*C.uchar)(&([]byte)(data)[0])
argsProtect.plaintextSize   = C.uint(len(data))

const BufSize int   = 256

textBuffer  := C.malloc(C.ulong(C.sizeof_char * BufSize))

argsProtect.ciphertext              = (*C.uchar)(textBuffer)
argsProtect.ciphertextBufferSize    = C.uint(BufSize)

status  = int(C.VeProtect(C.VeObj(fpeProtect), &argsProtect))
```

This still fails on the last line with "cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer".

Comment: It doesn’t mean it’s a pointer to a Go type, just to Go allocated memory. We would need a more complete example to see exactly what the problem is

Comment: It would help if I had a clue what I was looking for. I can't provide a complete example.

Comment: Start by showing how the argument types, and how they are declared and have values assigned. I would actually guess that `&argsProtect` is more likely the problem since you are taking the address of that value, so you definitely aren’t starting with a C pointer.

Comment: AH. That's it. Unfortunately, those assignments were already gnarly. I'm updating again with those assignments.

Comment: The problem isn't the type conversions, it's that the memory with the pointer is allocated in Go -- you need to allocate textBuffer in C.

Comment: Ok. I think I've fixed that particular problem, but the result is the same. I think the other variable expression needs fixing also. Updating again.